# Is there a way to clone an entity in erwin?

Tags: erwin

I want to clone an entity in the erwin Data Modeler, so as to add a new attribute to the new one. Anyway, if I try to just copy-paste, then the new field is added to both (the copied entity seems to be just a reference to the old one).